# Fixing the float and div alignment

Tags: html, css

So, I have this piece of code with me. I tried to align the class navLogo and navUl in the same line but I was not able to do that. Other thing is that I want the class navUl to float to the right.
Here is the HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
<title>Bookiro - Share books, thoughts and more..</title>
<meta charset = "utf-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="lib/css/style.css">
</head>

<body class="body">

<nav>
<div class="navLogo">
    Bookiro
</div>

<div class="navUl">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="">Features</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Stories</a></li>
        <li><a href="">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Sign In</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
</nav>
</body>
</html>
```

And CSS here..

```
body
{
color: #000305;
font-size: 100%;
font-family: "Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
text-align: left;
}

a
{
text-decoration: none;
}

.body
{
clear: both;
margin: 0 auto;
width: 70%;
}

nav
{
height: 50px;
background-color: #666;
}

nav .navLogo
{
width: 30%;
float: left;
}

nav .navUl
{
width: 70%;
float: left;
}

nav ul
{
list-style: none;
}

nav ul li
{
display: inline;
}

nav ul li a
{
display: inline-block;
text-align: center;
background-color: yellow;
height: 40px;
}
```

You help is very well appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Im not 100% sure if this is what you were wanting but you had a width of 70% on the `navUL` class and `float:left;` so i changed the float to right and made the width auto as well as added `padding` to both `navUL` and `navLogo` to vertically align

here is a **Codepen** http://codepen.io/noobskie/pen/wKBZqE

Comment: That helped. Thank you Tyler.